# Finding the minimum value of a column using PySpark Map Reduce

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parallel-processing, mapreduce, rdd

I'm looking to find out how I can use the `map` and `reduce` functions on a PySpark RDD to determine the smallest value in each of my RDD columns.

I understand that the `agg` function can be used on dataframes, but I really want to be able to perform the function on a large dataset in parallel.

e.g. in the below RDD example, I'd want to find the smallest values in the `Value 1` and `Value 2` columns.

```
+-------+---------+---------+
| Entry | Value 1 | Value 2 |
+-------+---------+---------+
| A     | 7.034   | 0.342   |
+-------+---------+---------+
| B     | 3.684   | 1.043   |
+-------+---------+---------+
| C     | 2.963   | 0.085   |
+-------+---------+---------+
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Most pyspark dataframe operations are done in parallel as well!

Answer (score 0):

Using the following `sample.txt` file as an example.

```
A,7.034,0.342
B,3.684,1.043
C,2.963,0.085
```

Using the following code we can get the minimum value of the `val1`, and `val2` columns

Firstly, each line mapped to a row using the `map` function, then we are using `reduce` to find the minimum value in each column

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

conf = SparkConf().setAppName('word count')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

def words_once(line):
    a = line.split(",")
    return (a[0], float(a[1]), float(a[2]))

def get_min_val1(x,y):
    if x[1] < y[1]:
        return x
    return y

def get_min_val2(x,y):
    if x[2] < y[2]:
        return x
    return y

text = sc.textFile("./sample.txt")
words = text.map(words_once)
words.foreach(lambda x: print(x, "yee"))

lowest_val1 = words.reduce(get_min_val1)[1]
lowest_val2 = words.reduce(get_min_val2)[2]

print("\n\n")
print("Val1 Min: {}".format(lowest_val1))
print("Val2 Min: {}".format(lowest_val2))
print("\n\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this, there might be more efficient solutions.

```
words_df = words.toDF(schema)
min_colName1 = words_df.order_by('colName1').first()['colName1']
min_colName2 = words_df.order_by('colName2').first()['colName2']
```